# .htaccess Directory Index not working in sub-folders

Tags: .htaccess, directoryindex

I have the following `.htaccess` file in my root folder:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)$ /users.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/followers$ /followers.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^@([^/]+)/highlights$ /highlights.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)(|/)$ /posts.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
```

If I write `localhost` in the address bar, it calls the index file correctly, but if I access the subfolder `localhost/support/` it does not detect the index file that is in this folder.

If I delete the last line `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php` it works, but I need it for the good functioning of other files.

Comment: Try : `RewriteRule ^([^\/.]+)$ $1.php`

Comment: @starkeen This works for `localhost/support/` and `localhost/support/index.php`, but not for `localhost/support/index`. How could I do it?